# How do I use ack's --ignore-file option?

Tags: ack

If I put

```
--ignore-file=example.txt
```

into my .ackrc or on the ack command-line, I get the error message "Invalid filter specification "example.txt".

The ack documentation says that the --ignore-file option takes a filter as an argument.  What's a filter?  How do I use --ignore-file to simply ignore a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use is:filename as your filter:

```
--ignore-file=is:example.txt
```

Filters are the same as [ack type definitions](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.14-man.html#defining_your_own_types) and can be a literal filename with is, a file extention with ext, or a regular expression to match.